# detect when a finger leaves the screen and update pointers

Tags: java, android, libgdx, multi-touch

I'm making a game where I accelerate holding two fingers on the screen , a finger in the left half and a finger in the right half of the display .
if you release your finger and let down the other , whatever it is I have to bend the vehicle based on the location of the finger . If you are located in the right half ( Gdx.grapchis.getWidth / 2 ) then I bend to the right ... and so the left .

part of input processor:

```
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
            if(pointer < 2)
            {
                CoordinateTouch tmp = new CoordinateTouch();
                tmp.x = screenX;
                tmp.y = screenY;
                coordinates.add(tmp);
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
            coordinates.clear();
            return false;
        }
```

my array of coordinates:

```
public class CoordinateTouch{
    float x;
    float y;
}

List<CoordinateTouch> coordinates;
```

control pointer in render method (group is my texture):

```
if(coordinates.size() > 1)
    {
        group.addAction(parallel(moveTo(realDest.x, realDest.y, (float) 15)));           
    }
    else
    {
        group.addAction(delay((float)1.5));
        group.clearActions();
        if(Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(0)) {
            if (Gdx.input.getX() < Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2) {
                group.addAction(parallel(rotateBy(velocityRotazionShip, (float) 0.03)));
            } else {
                group.addAction(parallel(rotateBy(-velocityRotazionShip, (float) 0.03)));
            }
        }
    }
```

My problem is that if I leave one finger detects it , and so far so good , but if I just leaned back his finger pulled away, I do not update the pointers and did not produce the piece of code group.addAction .

I also tried isButtonPressed and isKeypressed, isTouched(index) , but the result is the same.

Sorry for the English and I hope to have been clear .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood you corectly you have 3 cases:

1. Both disply sides are pressed -> move
2. Left display side pressed -> lean left
3. Right display side pressed -> lean right

If that assumption is correct, you would only need to `boolean`s:

```
boolean touchLeft, touchRight
```

Inside the `touchDown` you could do something like that:

```
 public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
 if (screenX < Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2)
     touchLeft = true;
 else
     touchRight = true;
 }
```

And in the `touchUp`:

```
public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    if (screenX < Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2)
        touchLeft = false;
    else
        touchRight = false;
}
```

Now inside the `render` you can just say:

```
if (touchLeft && touchRight)
    // move
else if (touchLeft)
    // lean left
else if (touchRight)
    // leanRight
else
    // do nothing or something else
```

If you want to support multiple fingers/side, you can change the `boolean`s to `int`s, giving the number of fingers/side. In the `touchDown` increment it, in the `touchUp` decrement it and in the render ask, if it is > 0.

Comment: you mentioned twice touchdown , maybe intenedevi touchup in the second ?
Thank You

Comment: @Mr.Developer Yes the second one should be `touchUp`, i just copied it and forgot to change the method name. Thanks. Did the answer help you or did i missunderstand your question?

Comment: I changed , you never know someone else arrivals so there confuse .
I try soon your solution , I will not fail to put the correct answer if it works . Thanks